ojdbc driver not found when deploying webApp on Tomcat
I have a Java Webapp that is built with Maven, and deployed on a Tomcat 11 server, using HttpServlet and JSP thechnologies. It's function is to fetch some data from an oracle 19c database, create a list of objects that contain yearly statistical data, than a servlet serves this list to a jsp page which the user can access via browser to view said statistical data in a table format. Pretty simple stuff. I used Netbeans idea to develop this, and I also created a test class, where i added a main function, this is what I used inside Netbeans to test my Database connection. In my Pom file I added the oracle db driver as dependency, when testing the connection inside Netbeans there was no problem with connecting to the database. However when I build the war file and deploy on Tomcat suddenly I get this error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/SKI_SCHOOL. So this is the issue, how come the dependency works in Netbeans but fails once it's deployed, I'm guessing that i'm doing something wrong when building the war or perhaps the pom.xml has some issue, but I don't know where to start even. Please help I will share my pom below:

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cc_internship</groupId>
    <artifactId>SkiSchoolReportWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SkiSchoolReportWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
            <version>23.5.0.24.07</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SkiSchoolReportWebApp</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.13.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>```


I don't use Maven so I can't tell you if there is a problem with your pom.xml file, however when I deploy a Web application to Tomcat and that application needs to access a database, I need to configure a data source. There are instructions in the documentation of [Apache] Tomcat.

Long story short: Do not bundle a JDBC driver with your web app. The system admin should install the appropriate JDBC driver into Tomcat, where it is automatically registered by Java SPI. Your app should be using DataSource, an instance of which is provided to your web app by Tomcat at runtime.
